# Searching a string in a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, substring

Hello
I have a string which contains a mail address. For example ( user@foo.bar.com )
And I have a list which contains only domains ('bar.com','stackoverflow.com') etc.

I want to search the list if it contains my string's domain. Right now I am using a code like this

```
if tokens[1].partition("@")[2] in domainlist:
```

tokens[1] contains the mail address and domainlist contains the domains.
But as you can see the result of `tokens[1].partition("@")[2]` will return `foo.bar.com` but my list has the domain `bar.com`.
How can I make this if statement return true? And it should be very fast because hundreds of mail addresses will come in every second

Comment: Using `.partition("@")[2]` will fail for certain types of email addresses. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908190/searching-a-string-in-a-list-in-python/5908265#5908265 for how to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
if any(tokens[1].endswith(domain) for domain in domainlist):
```

Comment: too simple, the domain 'foo.com' would match also 'somefoo.com'

Comment: Ooops, sorry... it has one problem... It returns true for 'me@foobar.com' if 'bar.com' is in the domainlist. Probably not what OP wants... :-(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908190/searching-a-string-in-a-list-in-python/5908265#5908265 in case `len(domainlist)>1000`, for a way to avoid doing 1000x the work. Otherwise this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

If speed is really an issue for you, you can look into methods like Aho-Corasick. There are plenty of implementations available, like `esmre`/`esm` http://code.google.com/p/esmre/

As pointed out by @Riccardo Galli, simple string matching will produce some false positives, so you can try with `esmre` first, adding according regexes into index, something like `index.enter("(^|\.){0}$".format(domain))`

Answer (score 1):

First, make `domainlist` a set. It will be faster to check whether there is something contained in it.

Second, add all 'superdomains' into this set, such as 'bar.com' for 'foo.bar.com'.

```
domainlist = ['foo.bar.com', 'bar2.com', 'foo3.bar3.foobar.com']
domainset = set()
for domain in domainlist:
    parts = domain.split('.')
    domainset.update('.'.join(parts[i:]) for i in xrange(len(parts)-1))

#domainset is now:
set(['bar.com',
     'bar2.com',
     'bar3.foobar.com',
     'foo.bar.com',
     'foo3.bar3.foobar.com',
     'foobar.com'])
```

And now you can test

```
if tokens[1].partition("@")[2] in domainset:
```

Answer (score 1):

Hundreds of mail addresses should not be an issue. The following is a one-liner:

```
any(domain.endswith(d) for d in MY_DOMAINS)
```

Here, you can do `user,sep,domain = address.rpartition('@')`. Otherwise, your current method will fail for email addresses such as `"B@tm4n"@something.com`, which are valid according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322

If performance becomes a factor, you can use a Trie (a kind of data structure). If performance is still a factor, you can use other tricks.

The above goes through each element in the domains you're checking, so if you have 1000 domains in your list, you need to do 1000 lookups for each email address. If this is an issue, you can do this to achieve `O(1)` per lookup (you also probably want to make sure you're not checking more than 5 suffixes, to protect yourself from maliciously crafted email addresses).

```
MY_DOMAINS = set(MY_DOMAINS)

def suffixes(domain):
    """
        suffixes('foo.bar.com') -yields-> ['foo.bar.com', 'bar.com', 'com']
    """
    while True:
        yield domain
        parts = domain.split('.',1)
        if len(parts>1)
            domain = parts[1]
        else:
            break
def isInList(address):
    user,sep,domain = address.rpartition('@')
    return any(suffix in MY_DOMAINS for suffix in suffixes(domain))
```

Answer (score 1):

Opposite to other answers, here 'foo.com' would not match also '@y.afoo.com'

```
def mailInDomains(mail,domains):

    for domain in domainList:
        dLen = len(domain)
        if mail[-dLen:]==domain and mail[-dLen-1] in ('.','@'):
            return True

    return False
```